# How to get single integer number using EditText

Tags: java, android-studio

I have set `inputType` property of `editText` to number and `maxLength` to `1`. I have tried some  options:

Here is my code:

```
EditText u1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.show_EditText);
Int check = integer.Parseint(u1.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: Then what is you want?

Comment: app get crash when text is null

Comment: @Hulk. Sorry I'm new here.. 
I tried to get integer value and multiply it by 5 and print.

' EditText unity1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.show_EditText);
    int   u1 = Integer.valueOf(unity1.getText().toString());
int tg1, g1 = 5;
 tg1 = g1 * u1; '

then i will display it in TextVieW but it Crash when EditText is empty or Null

Comment: So first check editbox have empty space or null then do other operation, i will post answer wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(ed != null || ed.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
Log.d("hulk","please enter value");
return;
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".